# Adding autogenerated column that computes frequencies

Tags: sql, calculated-columns, alter-table, generated-columns

I would like to create a generated column in my SQL table `products` who's value is automatically calculated by COUNTING the frequency of values in another column.

Please see example below, **`prod_cat_id_count`** is the result I am after :

| prod_id | prod_name | prod_cat_id | prod_cat_id_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | prod_name_1 | 1 | 2 - returns frequency of prod_cat_id |
| 2 | prod_name_2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | prod_name_3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | prod_name_4 | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | prod_name_5 | 3 | 3 |
| 6 | prod_name_6 | 3 | 3 |
| 7 | prod_name_7 | 4 | 2 |
| 8 | prod_name_8 | 4 | 2 |
| 9 | prod_name_9 | 5 | 2 |
| 10 | prod_name_10 | 5 | 2 |

Something like

```
ALTER TABLE products
ADD COLUMN prod_cat_id_count INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (COUNT(prod_cat_id) VIRTUAL;
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: [Why should I tag my rdbms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options for you to get out of this rabbit hole:

- create an AFTER INSERT trigger, that checks when a new record is inserted in your table and updates the frequencies (but syntax for this solution is very DBMS-dependant)
- create a view that computes your frequencies in a lazy way (great option if you have very frequent insert operations):

```
CREATE VIEW prod_frequencies AS 
SELECT prod_id,
       prod_name,
       prod_cat_id,
       COUNT(prod_name) OVER(PARTITION BY prod_cat_id) AS prod_cat_id_count
FROM tab;
```

When you need to show the updated frequencies, this will give you exactly what you need, given that your DBMS supports window functions.

Comment: I went for option 2 as I wasn't certain on the SQL syntax for the AFTER INSERT or for the ALTER TABLE piece either. After changing tab; to products it worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello @lemon,
I ve noticed this question and your solution creating a view.
I created the trigger in Oracle without any errors but when i try to insert no way-trigger failed etc.I m using Oracle 21c and Sql Server 2019.
Can you please create one in Oracle or Sql server?
This is what i did in Oracle
CREATE OR REPLACE  TRIGGER update_cate_trigger
before INSERT ON tab
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  l_cate NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_cate
  FROM tab
  WHERE cat_id = :NEW.cat_id;

  UPDATE tab
  SET cate = l_cate
  WHERE prod_id = :NEW.prod_id;
END;
/

Comment: Craft a new post, and link this post as a similar one with respect to your current scenario.